# Android Project refresh failed : gradle build failed

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.jar
Required by:
    HapiKey Project:camera:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jcenter to your repositories in your project-level build.gradle

`buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    // ...
    }`